# how to display xml data as it is in td in a table

Tags: json, xml

```
<html><table>
<tr>
<td>Heading 1</td> <td>Heading 2</td> <td>Heading 3</td> 
</tr>
<tr><td>value 1</td>  <td>value 2</td> 
<td>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfMENU_BO xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<MENU_BO>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <CreatedBy>0</CreatedBy>
    <CreatedOn>0001-01-01T00:00:00</CreatedOn>
    <ModifiedBy>0</ModifiedBy>
</MENU_BO>
</ArrayOfMENU_BO>
</td></tr>
</table></html>
```

In 2nd row 3rd column i'm displaying the xml data but when it was rendered in browser, it is not showing in that format. How can I show it in the same format as xml?

Comment: Browsers display HTML, so XML that doesn't contain HTML tags will not be displayed.  In order to display XML, you'll need to escape the <> with &lt; and &gt;.  There are several XML escape sites to do the conversion for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things:

(1) Use HTML tag `<pre>`

(2) As William already mentioned, you need to entity encode actual XML angle brackets: Use `&lt; and &gt; instead of < and >`

> HTML

```
<pre>&lt;?xml version="1.0"?&gt;
&lt;movies&gt;
 &lt;movie id="123"&gt;
  &lt;title&gt;Pulp Fiction&lt;/title&gt;
  &lt;year&gt;1994&lt;/year&gt;
  &lt;rating&gt;8.9&lt;/rating&gt;
 &lt;/movie&gt;
 &lt;movie id="124"&gt;
  &lt;title&gt;Memento&lt;/title&gt;
  &lt;year&gt;2000&lt;/year&gt;
  &lt;rating&gt;8.6&lt;/rating&gt;
 &lt;/movie&gt;
 &lt;movie id="124"&gt;
  &lt;title&gt;The Usual Suspects&lt;/title&gt;
  &lt;year&gt;2000&lt;/year&gt;
  &lt;rating&gt;8.6&lt;/rating&gt;
 &lt;/movie&gt;
&lt;/movies&gt;
</pre>
```

> Output in a browser

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<movies>
 <movie id="123">
  <title>Pulp Fiction</title>
  <year>1994</year>
  <rating>8.9</rating>
 </movie>
 <movie id="124">
  <title>Memento</title>
  <year>2000</year>
  <rating>8.6</rating>
 </movie>
 <movie id="124">
  <title>The Usual Suspects</title>
  <year>2000</year>
  <rating>8.6</rating>
 </movie>
</movies>
```